# In QT 4.6 w/ Webkit: How to handle popup window requests (WebView::createWindow)?

Tags: qt4, popup, webkit

I'm new to QT and have been trying to create a test browser. What I'm trying to do now is to handle js-based popup requests. After reading the QT documentation, I learned that I need to re-implement the QWebView::createWindow method to do just that.

Now I've re-implemented this method, but it seems to be not called when I try to click a link that triggers a popup window.

Can any one help me? Do I need to subclass both the WebView and WebPage classes? If so, how do I do that? I'm quite new to QT and I've done tons of searches and found nothing.

Thank you all in advance for any hint and advice!

Answer (score 4):

Did you remember to set the following options?

```
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);
```

And don't forget to call the parent class createWindow() method. The documentation has a note on that:

> Note: If the createWindow() method of
>   the associated page is reimplemented,
>   this method is not called, unless
>   explicitly done so in the
>   reimplementation.

Comment: @duncan,
Many thanks for your help!

I'm pretty sure the JavaScript is enabled, since all other js calls are working perfectly fine.

I tried to use the setAttribute call to enable to JavascriptCanOpenWindows, however I encounter this error message:

no matching function for call to QWidget::setAttribute...

I was using this code:

myWebView->page()->view()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);

Is this incorrect?

I believe this is an extremely noob question, and thanks again for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind my second question (in the comment area), here's what I did to capture the new window request (many thanks to Duncan's hint!):

```
page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptCanOpenWindows, true);
```

This was used inside the initiation process of the custom WebView class.

Hope this can be useful to someone.
Thanks!